# Move x-axis labels down from x-axis

Tags: r, plot, label

```
x<- structure(list(count = c(4259120, 4317840, 4444000, 4254240, 
4656800), the_date = structure(c(1389589200, 1389675600, 1389762000, 
1389848400, 1389934800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names =     c("count", 
"the_date"), row.names = c(51L, 406L, 664L, 197L, 196L), class = "data.frame")

par(mar = c(8, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(x$the_date, x$count, type="l", xaxt = "n",  xlab = "")
axis(1, labels = FALSE)
labels<-x$the_date
labels<-format(labels, format="%b-%d-%Y") 
text(x$the_date, par("usr")[3] - 0.75, srt = 55, adj = 1, labels = labels, xpd = TRUE)
```

I've tried adjusting the `par("usr")[3] - 0.75` offset as specified [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f), but the labels aren't moving at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a trick like this using 2 calls to `axis` functions. I am using here `axis.Date` since you deal with dates(better for formatting). Then you can ply with `line` argument t play with labels positions.

```
axis(1,labels=FALSE)
axis.Date(1,at = x$the_date,las=2, format= "%m-%d",line=0.5,tick=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to have them be rotated at a certain degree instead of just 90 degrees?

Comment: @tcash21 better to move to more higher plot libraries..like `ggplot2` or `lattice`.

Comment: Yea I figured. I'll go back to `ggplot2` for this. Thanks!